# How can I calculate metrics like mAP, F1 score and confusion matrix for Yolov4 for object detection?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, yolov4

I'm really new to this field of computer vision.
I have used this repo https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-custom-functions.

system: Win 10
name: yolov4-gpu
dependencies:

- python==3.7
- pip
- matplotlib
- opencv
- cudnn
- cudatoolkit==10.1.243
- pip:

  - tensorflow-gpu==2.3.0rc0
  - opencv-python==4.1.1.26
  - lxml
  - tqdm
  - absl-py
  - easydict
  - pillow
  - pytesseract
    I want to find the metrics for this model.
    Please help.
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is more of a statistics question, we dont need to see your  pip packages. but are you aware, that you need **labelled data**,(ground truth) to run a benchmark ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Really I don't know. I'm new to programing. I have followed a video and run the object detection code. It given me the output now I stuck with evaluating the model. Please suggest me how to calculate all the metrics. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this package](https://github.com/laclouis5/globox) (disclaimer: I’m the author) to compute all COCO metrics for a given couple of ground truths and predicted bounding boxes. You can install it using `pip`:

```bash
pip install globox
```

You first need to save the predictions in any supported format. For instance, if both the ground truths and the predictions are saved in YOLO format (txt files) you can print COCO metrics with:

```py
from globox import AnnotationSet, COCOEvaluator

gts = AnnotationSet.from_yolo("yolo/gts/folder/")
preds = AnnotationSet.from_yolo("yolo/preds/folder/")

evaluator = COCOEvaluator(gts, preds)
evaluator.show_summary()
```

You can achieve the same thing from the command line:

```bash
globox evaluate yolo/gts/folder/ yolo/preds/folder --format yolo --format_dets yolo
```

If you don't or can't save the predictions to in one of the supported format, you can parse them using the `BoundingBox.create(...)` function.

Take a look at the README of the repo for further information.

The confusion matrix can be computed with the help of [this](https://github.com/kaanakan/object_detection_confusion_matrix) other package.

Comment: Thank you so much @Louis Lac for the response. I will try what ever you have suggested. I will let you know whether I'm getting it or not. Thank you once again.

Comment: @Shaik did it solved your question?